# JQuery Validate Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined in Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

This is my Blade code, contains te view datospresupuesto:

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="shopping-cart" role="shopping-
      cart"action="cotizacion" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()}}">
      <div>
         @include('frontend.partials.productos')
         @include('frontend.partials.datospresupuesto')
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<!--/end container-->
```

This is my view of "datos presupuesto"

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre"  id="name" for="nombre" class="form-control required" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control required">
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is part of js file that contanis this rules  like validations about nombre, correo, etc.:

```
 var StepWizard = function() {
            return {
                initStepWizard: function() {
                        var form = $(".shopping-cart");
                        console.log(form);
                        form.validate({
                                    rules: {
                                        nombre: {
                                            required: true,
                                            minlength: 3,
                                            letters: true
                                        },

                                        apellidos: {
                                            required: true,
                                        }
```

Comment: It's saying it can't find `$('.shopping-cart');` which does exist in your view but you may be initialising the JS prior to it being available if you're attempting to load the view via AJAX. If you add `console.log($('.shopping-cart'));` to your javascript does console show an object or `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, show the form. The result is:         [form.shopping-cart, prevObject: m.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".shopping-cart"]
0
:
form.shopping-cart
context
:
document
length
:
1
prevObject
:
m.fn.init(1)
selector
:
".shopping-cart"
__proto__
:
Object(0)

Comment: wrap the step wizard initialization in $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Comment: Yes I did it.  <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            StepWizard.initStepWizard();
        });
    </script>